# Debugging Axios requests in React Native

Tags: debugging, react-native, axios

I'm trying to debug [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) requests in my React Native app using [axios-debug-log](https://github.com/Gerhut/axios-debug-log).

I've added the library: `npm install --save-dev axios-debug-log`

Before a user logs in and starts using the app, I set the local storage (or in RN's case, the [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)): `AsyncStorage.setItem('debug', 'axios')`

In the top of the file with my axios API requests, I added `require('axios-debug-log');`

However, I'm not seeing any logs when I use axios. The docs for axios-debug-log don't include any specifics about using the library with RN, so I'm not sure if there's something I'm doing wrong. If there is another library/ techniques I could use to debug axios requests in my RN app I would be open to using those as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using AsyncStorage will not work. You need to set NODE environment variable.

**Option 1**

Add the following code on top of your index.js file.

```js
let debug = require('debug');

debug.enable('axios');
```

**Option 2**

Other way you can do it is using npm 'babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables' npm package.

run

```js
npm install babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables
```

Now got to .babelrc file inside your react-native app directory and add following code.

```js
// .babelrc
 {
    “presets”: [“react-native”],
    “plugins”: [
          “transform-inline-environment-variables”
     ]
 }
```

Finally run your app with following command. It will set a node env variable DEBUG as axios.

```js
DEBUG=axios react-native run-ios
DEBUG=axios react-native run-android
```